# How to duplicate or move to another SVN url

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My current SVN URL is:

> http://xx.test.com:8001/A/B/C

I want to duplicate or move all staff including all of the change history under this URL to another URL like:

> http://xx.test.com:8001/D/E

Can this be done on an SVN client (TortoiseSVN), or does it need to be done on the SVN server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Project --> Tortoise SVN --> Relocate ---> Change the URL

[image]

Comment: TortoiseSVN does not even include an HTTP server. How is it going to physically move the repository?

Comment: This did not work for me.  I had the following error message: "Unable to connect to a repository at URL <myurl> Repository moved temporarily to <myurl>; please relocate."  It shows the same url in both places.  Which is confusing is me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your need to move Repository "A" to  Repository "D". To achieve this, you need to work on server side. First you need to dump the "Repo A" and reload to "Repo D". As per my knowledge, You cant move repository usingSVN client. Please correct me, if i am wrong.
[[Move subversion repository]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631164/how-can-i-move-my-repository-in-tortoise-svn)

Answer (score 1):

"It depends".

When you **see only** old-URL and new-URL, you can't be sure, are they belong to the same repository (with `/` root-path) or to different, i.e which part of URL is repository-URL and which - path inside repository.

If you'll see at `svn info` output, you **can** answer on this question, see @

```
URL: ...
Relative URL: ...
Repository Root: ...
```

fields and can select the right tool: for single-repository operation you'll copy with *svn-client* (using "Branch|tags"), for cross-repositories copies you have to use some *repository-administration* tools (svnadmin load|dump) and access to SVN-server