# Migrate Tortoise SVN from Windows server 2008 to Windows server 2012

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Could someone please help with the migration steps for migrating SVN from WS 2008 to WS2012? And also the challenges faced during doing the same.

Thanks!

Comment: will the Tortoise SVN version be the same after the migration?

Comment: Tortoise SVN is just a client. There is no "migration" of it - you install the software on the computer and that's that. What are you *really* trying to migrate? A repository? A working copy? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

1. stop your SVN server so no-one can commit to it while you're migrating
2. copy the repo files from disk from box A to box B
3. install SVN server on box B and point it at the copied repo
4. start SVN server and svn "relocate" any clients who want to access the new URL.

that's it. You could migrate using svnhotcopy or svnsync or svn dump/load but if you're moving from Windows to Windows, you can simply copy the directory containing the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Windows Server Migration Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj134202) and [this SVN question from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631164/how-can-i-move-my-repository-in-tortoise-svn).